# ArcGIS ClassBreaksRenderer with local JSON

Tags: geojson, arcgis-js-api

I've been trying to color polygons based on attributes using the ClassBreaksRenderer in the ArcGIS JS API.  My data source is a local json file, which I suspect is the reason that it's not working.  I've based my testing on the example provided in the documentation:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/renderer_class_breaks.html
Where I can replace the FeatureLayer pointer as follows:

original:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", ...
```

Replaced:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("./data/check.json", ...
```

The geojson layer renders and all of the attributes are visible in the pop-out when the polygons are clicked, but I can't seem to apply any color to the file, it just renders in a default shade of semi-transparent green. In fact, the only way that I can get the color of the json layer to change at all is if I require the simple renderer: `esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer`
then configure as follows, still following the ClassBreaksRenderer example otherwise:

```
var simpleJson = {
 "type": "simple",
 "label": "",
 "description": "",
 "symbol": {
     "color": [255,0,50,200],
     "style": "esriSFSSolid",
     "type": "esriSFS"
    }
}

featureLayer.renderer = new SimpleRenderer(simpleJson);
```

I'm wondering whether the API doesn't support a local json file, in which case I will consider switching to Leaflet for this project.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can't instantiate a FeatureLayer with an uri to a file in your local file system, it should be a valid REST Service in any of the valid formats (ArcGIS REST, WMS, etc).

What you can do in your scenario is to use a FeatureCollection to build your FeatureLayer and move on.

Take a look at this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html

Let me know if it helps.